# Python: extracting asterisked strings from text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am a Python (and programming) noob, and I am trying to use Python 3 to extract Markdown-italicised text like this

```
*R v Stephenson*
```

from a multi-lined block of text in a separate file, and then dump that in a set. My code is as follows:

```
import re
filename = input("Name of file: ")
readfile = open(filename, "r+").read()
cases = re.findall(r"\*.*\b\s\bv\b\s\b.*\*",readfile)
print("All cases:", cases)
```

It works fine, except for when there is more than one italicised chunk in the same line, eg:

```
*R v Stephenson* was a case, but so was *R v Stephens*, and the two should not be confused.
```

In these instances, it adds the entire section between the first and last asterisk to the set. How can I persuade Python to treat each instance of the regexed phrase separately? More importantly, does anybody know why it does it like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting `cases` to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `*` (also `+` and `?`) in regular expression is greedy by default, which means they would match as many characters as possible. You can use `?` to make the regex non-greedy:

```
cases = re.findall(r"\*.*?\b\s\bv\b\s\b.*?\*",readfile)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iV8cC3/1)

[Detailed Explanation](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap)

Comment: Thank you very much! Would upvote but need more reputation :)

Comment: @WilliamThong [Accept this answer if it seems helpful.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)